# given two elements, wrap html around heterogeneous elements?

Tags: jquery

Given two ordered but not necessarily sequential sibling elements, how can I wrap html around them?

```
$(element_a).before( "<span class='wow'>" );
$(element_b).after( "</span>" );
```

The above not working, as it closes the opening tag for me, and does not insert the latter.

(The siblings are a motley crew of types and classes, so using slice to help with this task is difficult, but maybe I've not thought it through.)

Comment: Are you wanting to wrap elements that are inbetween the siblings also? (if they are not sequential)

Comment: How do you determine whether any two elements should be considered heterogenous? What are you comparing about them?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to put a single span around all of the elements between `element_a` and `element_b` (including those two elements), and I've given an answer on that basis, but it might help if you could provide some simple before and after example html...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to put a single span around all of the elements between `element_a` and `element_b` (inclusive).

The [`.wrapAll()` method](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) can do this quite nicely once you figure out how to get all of those elements into a single jQuery object, but something like this should work:

```
var $els = $(element_a);
$els = $els.add( els.nextUntil(element_b) ).add(element_b)

$els.wrapAll("<span class='wow' />");
```

This starts with a jQuery object containing just `element_a`, then uses the [`.add()` method](http://api.jquery.com/add/) and [`.nextUntil()` method](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) to add in all the elements between `element_a` and `element_b`, and finally adds in `element_b`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("<span class='wow'></span").appendTo('#container');
$(element_a, element_b).each(function() {
   $(this).clone(true).appendTo(".wow");
   $(this).remove()
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KZtE9/1/

Comment: the thing about `.wrap()`, is that it will wrap each element separately - rather than both in the same wrapper.